# power of analytic function is still analytic in Krasner sense

Tags: analytic-functions, p-adic

In page 54 of his book, "Analytic elements in $p$-adic analysis" Escassut claims that if $f$ is analytic in Krasner sense in a set $D$ of a ultrametric field, so is $f^n$ for any positive integer $n$.
But no proof is provided and the author says "it is easily seen". Me, I see nothing!!

Can anyone explain the claim?
Thanks in advance